# Shipment confirmation email option not showing

Tags: shipment

I have various instances of Magento running and I have a discrepancy in the admin for 2 of them - on one order section when I go to ship an order I have an option to notify the customer and on the other I don't - please see attached screengrabs - can anyone advise?

thanks

[image: With Email Option and without]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `Email copy of shipment` checkbox can be disabled from configuration.
Looking in the template that renders that section you will see this:

```
      <?php if ($this->canSendShipmentEmail()): ?>
      <p>
          <label class="normal" for="send_email"><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Email Copy of Shipment') ?></label>
          <input id="send_email" name="shipment[send_email]" value="1" type="checkbox" />
      </p>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

This means that the checkbox is shown only if `$this->canSendShipmentEmail()` evaluates to `true`.
Going deeper on this you will see that the config path `sales_email/shipment/enabled` determines if it's allowed or not.

The value for that config path can be changed from `System->Configuration->Sales Emails->Shipment->Enabled`.
Set that to `Yes` and you will see the checkbox in your other website.